# iOS 10 UIImagePickerController black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, xcode8

I'm facing a strange problem....
On devices running `iOS 10` camera preview shows black screen.
But in **older version it works fine**.
I'm using `UIImagePickerController` with

```
self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

My info.plist file:

[image]

[image]

Example project: https://github.com/arturdev/cameraTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with different approach.

Don't make subclass of UIImagePickerController because Apple does not support subclass of UIImagePickerController.

Important

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
>   The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified,
>   with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

Here is alternate solution:

Add this code in UIViewController

> ```
> self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
> self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
> self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
>
> [self.view addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
> [self addChildViewController:self.imagePickerController];
> [self.imagePickerController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
> ```

Working Fine in all iOS version and devices. :):)

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIImagePickerController()` instead of any other initializer.

I am facing the same problem, and it is caused by calling the wrong initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add privacy setting for camera to info.plist to access camera if you are using Xcode 8

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons could be one of below listed, try and check if it help:

------ ***Try Code related to show `UIImagePickerController` in Main thread:***

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^(void){

    //Code related to show UIImagePickerController

    .....

    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.imagePickerController];
    [self.imagePickerController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    .....

});
```

***----- Check info.plist >Bundle display name:***

If *info.plist >Bundle display name* is blank then add **Bundle display name** key with value **your application name**.

***------ Set privacy setting for camera to `info.plist` for accessing camera:***

Camera :

Key     : `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`
Value   : `$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use`

***------ Don't subclass `UIImagePickerController`:***(as ***Ankit Gupta's*** answer suggest)

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.

Assign a custom view to the `cameraOverlayView` property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

Reference:https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: `-viewDidLoad` method is already executing in main thread, so no need to dispatch that in main thread again. 
My info.plist is already modified, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to present the UIImagePickerController that's why you're getting the blank screen :-

```
[self presentViewController:yourImagePickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: then what does **older version it works fine** in bold means?

Answer (score 0):

are you using UIActionSheet to show UIImagePickerController? I solved it by replace UIActionSheet by UIAlertController. Because UIAlertView may will cause unhappend bugs.DO NOT USE UIAlertView anymore;)

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue. Something weird with iOS10. So here i came up with the solution. Even though you are using *UIImagePickerController* or extending it with your viewController. Just Make an instance of UIImagePickerController and present it in viewDidLoad.

**UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [UIImagePickerController alloc];**

**[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];**